# Custom sorting and values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sorting

I want to sort some table data but with a custom order:

I want to show 2nd result at first, then 1st, then 3rd, 4th etc.

This is part of my query:

```
SELECT order FROM table ORDER BY order DESC LIMIT 0
```

It will give me values like `8`, `6` , `5` , `3` , `2` , `1`

but I need to get `6`, `8` , `5` , `3` , `2` , `1` (second result becomes first)

And those values (`8`, `6` , `5` ....) will never be same.

How can I do this?

P.S: it is hosted on `godaddy`, so I'm not sure defining a custom function would work and I'm using `CodeIgniter` if that would help.

Comment: you could add extra field like "sort_order" in your table and sort the rows according to this field's value...

Comment: @Sudhir I know but I want to learn how this is done in SQL side, that's the main reason I asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can UNION three querys:

- second result
- first result
- rest

Comment: That's what I've been missing, sometimes you think more complicated where the result is right in front of you :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this ordering applies only in the 2 first values then you could execute the query as you have it and then switch the 2 first results in the client.

Comment: I also thought of that, but the reason I wanted to ask is that I want to know how this is done in SQL side.